# Can't retrieve the menu item in the ActionBar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

So i have this menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Settings">
</item>
```

I add i t to the View like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And then i would like to set the Text before it really gets shown and it thought i would have to do it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.getItem(R.id.action_settings);
    item.setTitle(langRes.getTextForKey("settings"));
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I get an IndexOutofBoundsException and the Menu when i debug it in the onPrepareOptionsMenu doesn't contain any Items!!  What am i doing wrong please?

Comment: on which line you got error...

Comment: In the onPrepareOptionsMenu in the first line: "MenuItem item = menu.getItem(R.id.action_settings);

Comment: is your problem resolved ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);` instead of `MenuItem item = menu.getItem(R.id.action_settings);` then your problem will resolved.

Comment: he is right in getItem you pass the index of the item you want to get, and in findItem you pass the ID of the item you want to find.